# Form Briefly Clones and then Disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

While I managed to get my example to work, the code that I was testing it for doesn't seem to like it. When I click the add button, the duplicated form will appear on screen for a second then immediately vanish. I basically does the same thing in JSFiddle, though it either replaces the whole thing with an error message:{"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', 'form': , 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field': , 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_wrap', 'form': , 'html_name': 'js_wrap', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_wrap', 'label': u'Js wrap', 'field': , 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_wrap'}"}

or it will give me a Forbidden 403 error. I did a runthrough with Firebug and I'm guessing there's something in the HTML/CSS that JQuery doesn't like, I just don't know what.

HTML

```
<form method="post">
<fieldset id='EmployeeInfo' style='float: right'>
    <legend>Enter New Employee</legend>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class='td_small'>First Name:</td>
            <td class='td_wide'>
                <input id='EmpFirst' class='maxField' type='text' maxlength='35' />
            </td>
            <td class='td_small'>M.I.</td>
            <td class='td_xtrasmall'>
                <input id='EmpMI' class='minField' type='text' maxlength='35' />
            </td>
            <td class='td_mid'>Last Name:</td>
            <td class='td_wide'>
                <input id='EmpLast' class='maxField' type='text' maxlength='35' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Address:</td>
            <td colspan='2'>
                <input id='EmpAddress' class='mostField' type='text' maxlength='35' />
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Apt. No.</td>
            <td>
                <input id='EmpAptNo' class='maxField' type='text' maxlength='35' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>City:</td>
            <td>
                <input id='EmpCity' class='maxField' type='text' maxlength='25' />
            </td>
            <td>State:</td>
            <td>
                <select id='EmpState'>
                    <option></option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>ZIP:</td>
            <td>
                <input id='EmpZIP' class='maxField' type='text' maxlength='25' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>SSN:</td>
            <td>
                <input id='EmpSSN' class='maxField' type='text' maxlength='25' />
            </td>
            <td>Gender:</td>
            <td>
                <select id='EmpGender'>
                    <option></option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>Date of Birth:</td>
            <td>
                <input id='EmpDOB' class='maxField' type='text' maxlength='25' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Marital Status:</td>
            <td>
                <select id='EmpMarital'>
                    <option>Single</option>
                    <option>Married</option>
                    <option>Married/Filing Separately</option>
                    <option>Other</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>Dependants:</td>
            <td>
                <select id='EmpDepend'>
                    <option>0</option>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                    <option>6</option>
                    <option>7</option>
                    <option>8</option>
                    <option>9</option>
                    <option>10+</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>Head of Household:</td>
            <td>
                <input id='EmpHOH' type='checkbox' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Disability:</td>
            <td>
                <input id='EmpDisabled' type='checkbox' />
            </td>
            <td>US Citizen:</td>
            <td>
                <input id='EmpCitizen' type='checkbox' />
            </td>
            <td>I-9 Form:</td>
            <td>
                <input id='EmpINine' type='checkbox' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
<br/>
<button id="add" style="text-align: center; width: 20%;float: right;">New Employee</button>
```

Javascript

```
//Dupe form and append number every id attribute
(function () {

var count = 0;
$("#add").on("click", function () {

    var source = $("#EmployeeInfo"),
        clone = source.clone();

    clone.find(":input").attr("id", function (i, val) {
        return val + count;
    });

    clone.insertBefore(this);

    count++;
});
})();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c4dc0thx/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking the `New Employee` button effectively is submitting the form. Just use `preventDefault()` in your jQuery to stop the form from submitting. Either that or move the `button` outside of the `<form>` tags.

```
//Dupe form and append number every id attribute
(function () {

    var count = 0;
    $("#add").on("click", function (e) {

        // Prevent the form from submitting
        e.preventDefault();

        var source = $("#EmployeeInfo"),
            clone = source.clone();

        clone.find(":input").attr("id", function (i, val) {
            return val + count;
        });

        clone.insertBefore(this);

        count++;
    });

})();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c4dc0thx/5/